# PowerMockito final method invoke verification not working

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock

Im testing a Task class that runs until an **AtomicBoolean** value changes. I'm using PowerMockito because get() method of AtomicBoolean instance is final.
**MyTaskTest** looks like this:

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.times;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(AtomicBoolean.class)
public class MyTaskTest {

    private AtomicBoolean stopReceiving;
    private MyTask task;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        stopReceiving = PowerMockito.mock(AtomicBoolean.class);
        task = new MyTask(stopReceiving);
    }

    @Test
    public void test_run_when_StopReceivingIsFalseFromTheBeginning_should_invokeGetOnlyOnce() {
        // given
        PowerMockito.when(stopReceiving.get()).thenReturn(false);
        // when
        task.run();
        // then
        verify(stopReceiving, times(1)).get();
    }

}
```

And **MyTask** class looks like this:

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

public class MyTask implements Runnable {

    private final AtomicBoolean stopReceiving;

    MyTask(AtomicBoolean stopReceiving) {
        if (stopReceiving == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("stopReceiving is null. This argument should not be null");
        }

        this.stopReceiving = stopReceiving;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (stopReceiving.get() == true) {
            System.out.println("I should not get to here!");
        }
    }
}
```

The problem here is that check `verify(stopReceiving, times(1)).get();` fails with:

> Wanted but not invoked
>   java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean.get(); Actually, there were
>   zero interactions with this mock.

which does not make sense to me because it is clearly called in `run()` method. I even debugged it and it passed through `run` method, but somehow did not increment invoke counter on it. What am I doing wrong here?
P.S. I'm using PowerMockito version 1.6.2

**What I tried**

- Changing verify call to be called without `times(1)`. Didn't help
- Upgrading powermockito version to 1.6.3. Didn't help
- Adding **MyTask** into **MyTaskTest** as inner class, which somehow worked, meaning that verify call passed, but I wanted to have **MyTask** in the other file as separate class, which still does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running into this trouble because you're trying to mock a system class. As [specified in the PowerMock documentation](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/MockSystem), PowerMock can't prepare system classes for test, so you need to prepare the class that calls the system class instead as you have in your answer.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(MyTask.class)
public class MyTaskTest {
```

---

**Under the hood:** Normal Mockito works by dynamically creating a subclass of the class you're mocking, and returning that instead; the delegation to Mockito happens through normal polymorphism. With `final` methods, Java doesn't need to do that virtual method lookup for dynamic dispatch; Java knows which implementation to call at compile time, and calls the implementation via static dispatch before Mockito can intervene.

PowerMock works around this by rewriting (bytecode-manipulating) the class that contains the final method, so that the implementation changes to delegate to EasyMock or Mockito stubs and mocks; in order for this to take effect, though, PowerMock has to install the modified class (`AtomicBoolean` here) early enough in the classpath that it overrides any other implementation it can find.

However, you can't ever install a replacement higher in priority than the system classes, because they're already loaded in the root classloader; nothing will pre-empt them. PowerMock works around *this* by rewriting your system-under-test, replacing the call to AtomicBoolean.get() with a call to a replacement method that PowerMock *can* modify. Therefore, it is not the case that "PowerMockito is somehow treating final methods as special", it is the case that `javac` treats them as special (with a static-dispatch call) and PowerMock treats system classes as special (because it can't override them the usual way).

---

**Related reading:** Lukáš Krejčí's ["The Dark Powers of PowerMock"](https://metlos.wordpress.com/2012/09/14/the-dark-powers-of-powermock/)

Side notes:

- For your use-case in particular, you probably don't need a mock AtomicBoolean at all; use a real one on a different thread, test that the thread is alive, set the boolean, and test that the thread is dead. You may need to [poll over time](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/master/src/main/java/org/mockito/internal/verification/VerificationOverTimeImpl.java#L76), the way Mockito does for its [`timeout`](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#22) verification mode.
- Don't forget that `stopReceiving.get() == true` can always be replaced with `stopReceiving.get()`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) "Mocking system class" link that you gave me pointed me in the right direction. I figured out that solution which I used is pretty much OK. 
On the side notes:
I am not found of using real objects in unit tests,  especially with timeouts when writing Unit tests for a class.
I'm aware that `stopReceiving.get() == true` is the same as `stopReceiving.get()`, it's just my style preference, but thanks for pointing it out ;)

Comment: @Damir I consider this case a pure overuse of mocks; though avoiding breakable "real objects" from your own system is often a good idea, if you can't trust AtomicBoolean's straightforward behavior, how can you trust ArrayList, Integer, or ClassLoader? And who guarantees your mock behaves realistically? Allowing yourself the use of well-tested libraries in unit tests, especially the system library, will likely make your tests clearer and more maintainable.

Comment: I understand you, but for this particular case I would have to create new thread, like you said, where I would change atomic boolean value after particular time. It is somehow more convenient to me to tell my atomic boolean mock to return "true" first two times and then "false" on get() method called, then do this with timeouts. I will try to use your input in my future unit testing :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding `MyTask.class` to `@PrepareForTest` annotation fixed the problem.

```
...
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({AtomicBoolean.class, MyTask.class})
public class MyTaskTest {
...
```

I couldn't find any info on why is that needed. Only explanation is that **PowerMockito** is somehow treating *final*  methods as special, so in order for verify to work, you need to add a class that is using the mock with final method call mocked.